# Transfer speed Android Wear DataApi?

Tags: wear-os, android-wear-data-api

What transfer speed can I expect when transferring data from phone to wearable using the Wearable DataApi?

My idea is to transfer files to the wearable from the phone. It's loads of images so I zip them first and then transfer the zip file as an asset. The file is about 30MB and it takes around 3 minutes to sync them to the wearable. Is that the speed I can expect? It feels really slow.

Answer (score 0):

Bluetooth 3 has same speed as bluetooth 4 so 25mbps.

This means around 3mb per second which should mean the 30mb file should take around 10 seconds.

Comment: Thanks. It seems it's much slower. Also found this link: http://www.droid-life.com/2014/10/24/how-to-store-music-on-android-wear-for-offline-playback/

It says:
"Note 3:  You first have to download the music to your phone. Once that completes, the automatic transfer begins happening from phone to Wear device, which takes a while. A 15-track album just took about 10-15 minutes to complete between my new Moto X and G Watch R."